# onClick function - automatically copies data from spreadsheets' static field

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd be very glad for help with some ideas for code of extension that, on pressing on the icon in chrome, automatically copies a text from static field in spreadsheet, like this:
http://tinyurl.com/bwfumls

I have tried many times to play with onClick function, but it didn't work for me. Thanks a million for your help or for some hints on the materials I could read to learn it.

damian

Comment: Question is too broad. Please, submit some sample of the code that you are trying to use, along with error messages or lacks of functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a content script within your extension that captures the `onclick` event of the table cell in Google Docs. This is the HTML source for the area you are interested in.

```
<div class="cell-input" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr">EXAMPLE OF TEXT THAT WOULD BE COPIED ON CLICK<br></div>
```

Here's some JQuery you can embed in your script to isolate the contents of the cell.

```
$(".cell-input").click(function(){
   var cellContents = $(".cell-input").text();
});
```

You could then store this in a background page and pull it out on the pop-up page that would appear when you click the Chrome extension icon. This is just the general methodology so you'll need to do a bit more research on the mechanisms I have mentioned here.

Content Scripts (to interact with the Google Docs page):
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Message Passing (to get the variable from the page into the popup via a background.js):
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Great stuff. I am still learning programming, so it will take me a while until I got it! :-)